# XMLHttpRequest cannot load <url> due to access control checks [IOS]

Tags: ios, get, request, axios

I'm trying to make a get request from my ios app to my server via axios. But unfortunately I receive the following error:

```
Preflight response is not successful
XMLHttpRequest cannot load <my-server-url> due to access control checks.
Failed to load resource: Preflight response is not successful
```

The url is accesable on the safari.
On android the request works properly.

```
  axios
    .get('<url>')
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      if (res.status === 200) {
        // some action
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      if (err.status === 500) {
        // error
      } else {
        // error
      }
    })
```

So I wondering why this problem is only with ios? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header so you need to add this header to the response from your server.

```
headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}
```